# sequelize-typescript many-to-many relationship model data with

Tags: postgresql, typescript, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript) library, and am trying to achieve the following relationship:

Team.ts

```
@Scopes({
  withPlayers: {
    include: [{model: () => User}]
  }
})
@Table
export default class Team extends Model<Team> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  name: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => TeamPlayer)
  players: User[];
}
```

User.ts

```
@Scopes({
  withTeams: {
    include: [{model: () => Team, include: [ () => User ]}]
  }
})
@Table
export default class User extends Model<User> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  firstName: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  lastName: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Team, () => TeamPlayer)
  teams: Team[];
}
```

TeamPlayer.ts

```
@DefaultScope({
  include: [() => Team, () => User],
  attributes: ['number']
})
@Table
export default class TeamPlayer extends Model<TeamPlayer> {

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  userId: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Team)
  @Column
  teamId: number;

  @Unique
  @Column
  number: number;
}
```

Now when querying for player, you get the object with the following data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Doe's Team",
  "players": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "TeamPlayer": {
        "userId": 1,
        "teamId": 1,
        "number": 32
    }
 }]
}
```

Now there are couple of things that I cannot get done..

1) I want to rename the `TeamPlayer` to something like "membership"; but not by changing the name of the class
2) the content of `TeamPlayer` should not have the id`s, but I want it to contain the data of the team, for example:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
  "membership": {
     "number": 32
 }
```

In the above classes, I tried to set a scope to the `TeamPlayer` class to only include `number` inside the `TeamMember` inclusion, but no effect.

I used to have the `TeamPlayer` class have direct memberships to `team` and `player`, but that solution added redundant  `id`  to the `TeamPlayer` class, and also did not prevent duplicate memberships in the team. I could indeed manually (= in code) prevent duplicates in these situations, but that does not feel elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding one-to-many relationships from `TeamPlayer` to `User` and `Team`, and also figured out the way to make the `teamId` + `userId` pair unique by adding two more fields with `@ForeignKey` like this:

**TeamPlayer.ts**

```
@Table
export default class TeamPlayer extends Model<TeamPlayer> {

  @BelongsTo(() => Team)
  team: Team;

  @ForeignKey(() => Team)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  teamId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user: User;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  userId: number;

  @Column
  number: number;
}
```

**User.ts**

```
@Table
export default class User extends Model<User> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  firstName: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  lastName: string;

  @HasMany(() => TeamPlayer)
  teams: TeamPlayer[];
}
```

**Team.ts**

```
export default class Team extends Model<Team> {
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  name: string;

  @HasMany(() => TeamPlayer)
  players: TeamPlayer[];
}
```

This solution allows me to control the included query attributes via scopes, and gives me proper object output.

Comment: I think `teams` column of User model should be `@HasMany(() => Team)` instead of `TeamPlayer`. Is it correct?