# Sequelize Typescript many-to-many specify 'through' Model attributes

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using sequelize-typescript and trying to not include the 'through' model (UserRole) in the many-to-many association when a get a User.

When I get a user, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "isVerified": true,
    "verificationToken": "",
    "passwordResetToken": null,
    "createdAt": "2022-02-17T03:04:34.099Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-17T03:05:20.754Z",
    "roles": [
        {
            "name": "SUPERADMIN",
            "UserRole": {
                "userId": 1,
                "roleId": 2,
                "createdAt": "2022-02-17T03:05:32.474Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-02-17T03:05:32.474Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally, the "UserRole" property in the "roles" array would not be there. Or, at the very least, I would be able to change the name from "UserRole" to "userRole" and remove the "userId" and "roleId" attributes.

I have tried specifying the "as" property on the association, creating default scopes for each of the model, all to no avail. This person [sequelize-typescript many-to-many relationship model data with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130037/sequelize-typescript-many-to-many-relationship-model-data-with) had a similar issue, but was concerned with the HasMany relationship, where I am looking at the BelongsToMany relationship. My model files look like this:

user.model.ts

```
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  DataType,
  HasMany,
  BelongsToMany,
  DefaultScope,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import { RefreshToken } from "./refreshToken.model";
import { Role } from "./role.model";
import { UserRole } from "./userRole";

@DefaultScope(() => ({
  include: [{ model: Role, attributes: ["name"], include: [] }],
}))
@Table({ tableName: "user", underscored: true })
class User extends Model {
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  email!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  password!: string;

  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  isVerified!: boolean;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  verificationToken!: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  passwordResetToken!: string;

  @HasMany(() => RefreshToken, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  refreshTokens!: RefreshToken[];

  @BelongsToMany(() => Role, {
    through: { model: () => UserRole },
  })
  roles!: Role[];

  @HasMany(() => UserRole, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  userRoles!: UserRole[];
}

export { User };
```

role.model.ts

```
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  DataType,
  HasMany,
  BelongsToMany,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import { User } from "./user.model";
import { UserRole } from "./userRole";

@Table({ tableName: "role", underscored: true, timestamps: false })
class Role extends Model {
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  name!: "ADMIN" | "SUPERADMIN";

  @BelongsToMany(() => User, {
    through: { model: () => UserRole },
  })
  users!: User[];

  @HasMany(() => UserRole, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  userRoles!: UserRole[];
}

export { Role };
```

userRole.model.ts

```
import {
  Table,
  Model,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
  PrimaryKey,
  Column,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import { Role } from "./role.model";
import { User } from "./user.model";

@Table({ tableName: "user_role", underscored: true })
class UserRole extends Model {
  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user!: User;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  userId!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Role)
  role!: Role;

  @ForeignKey(() => Role)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  roleId!: number;
}

export { UserRole };
```

Comment: If you are using the defaultScope in the user model, instead of `include: []`, try having `through: { attributes: [] }`.  This is to remove any attributes from through table (UserRole) in response.

Answer (score 1):

Emma's answer is totally correct, but I would like to provide a small example to make it clearer.

When you include a ManyToMany relationship, include directly the final table and not the through table.
So if you want to interact with the through table you have to do it from "inside" the include.

Normaly you would do :

```
ModelA.findOne(where, include: [ModelB]);
```

But to access the through model you have to do :

```
ModelA.findOne(where, include: [{model: ModelB, through: { attributes: ['']}}]);
```

In the second example we tell Sequelize to do the ManyToMany relationship but not to select anything from the linking table.
Note than you can put all the properties of an include (like a where for example) in this through object. It can be useful if you try to do some operation on the through model.

An other important point: DefaultScopes and Scopes can enter in conflict with the property "attributes". So it's better to sitck to one of them and avoid mixing them in one request.